# Memory leak due to class structure

Tags: python, memory, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I have developed a python tool that interacts with various power simulation softwares to perform analytical studies. After much testing, it seems that the structure of the tool is causing a memory leak when running through a study. It seems odd that where the class sits would affect how memory is being managed. Is this possible?

There is a particular function that is embedded in a class that is accessed through a series of overarching classes. The memory leak only occurs for one particular software. If I bring this class closer to the top, i.e. not embedded so many classes deep, the memory leak goes away. Or if I skip interacting with the power simulation software with this specific function it goes away, so I know it is particular to this software, this function and the structure of the tool. The memory usage grows with each call of this function.

I am not familiar with tracing memory leaks, but have tried running gc.collect() at the highest level script controlling the number of studies being performed as well as right after the function is call and in both cases it returns 0. Pympler indicates that there are no classes specific to the Python tool growing in memory. Is there a way I can better target the memory usage of this function?

Cheers!

I should also note that the function that is causing the memory leak is not my own code. It is part of the class developed by the power simulation software provider for access.

Comment: Check `memory_profiler`: https://github.com/fabianp/memory_profiler

Comment: I have used psutil directly to try to monitor memory usage to target where the increase was coming from. This helped somewhat, but now I need something that can flush the memory build being caused by this function.

Comment: You first need to find what is actually causing the leak before you can think of a strategy to 'flush' it. If `gc.collect()` doesn't reduce the memory usage you have dangling references, inner references or anything of that kind and you need to find and fix that part. Memory profilers exists precisely for that reason.

Comment: Is there a good thread you can point me to demonstrating how to use a memory profiler to find there inner or dangling references? The memory usage was going up and down within each analysis iteration, but the memory usage grows overall, so it was hard to use it to even pinpoint the function.

Comment: I guess to your point of finding what is actually causing the leak, I have edited the question to include that the function I have targeted as being the cause is a part of a class developed bu the power simulation software provider. I do not have access to the variables in this function. Is there a way to dump all memory associated with it?